# MySQL 'select now()' out of sync with linux 'date'

Tags: mysql, linux

*(I hope someone can solve this quick sharp because this is on my production server)*

It's really in the title. I thought mysql got its datetime from the machine it is installed on... well I was wrong!

currently its 2.30pm

linux says its 2.30pm

MySQL says its 9.30am?!?!

What should I do because it's date stamping everything in the database with the wrong time?

Comment: Run this "SQL", `show variables like '%time_zone%';` , what's the output ?

Comment: `system_time_zone EST` and `time_zone SYSTEM`

Comment: but if I do `date` on the server I get `Thu Jan 20 15:22:06 GMT 2011`

Comment: can I do `SET GLOBAL system_time_zone='SYSTEM'` and then restart MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Someone posted something very similar to this and then deleted it. Sorry I couldn't understand your answer initially, I just didn't understand the context)*

Change the timezone of the server from the command line with:

```
# export $TZ=Europe/London
```

and then restart mysql with (RedHat/Fedora/CentOS):

```
# service mysqld restart
```

(Deban/Ubuntu):

```
# /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: You probably want to make sure the change persists across restarts by actually changing the system timezone file: `$ echo "Europe/London" | sudo tee /etc/timezone`

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the commands:

```
mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime_original
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Singapore /etc/localtime
service mysqld restart
```

verify and it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to set the mysql system time zone to UTC.  Add the line:

```
timezone=UTC
```

To the `[mysqld_safe]` section of `/etc/my.cnf`, and restart mysqld.

Comment: Definitely has to be a timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem with you locale? Maybe one of the two calculates the +x from your locale, but the other just uses the system-time?