# Time zone in Linux and in MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to set the time zone in MySQL so that it matches the Ubuntu 20.04 time zone.  When I check the error.log for MySQL I see a different set of data for the time zone.

Here is what I have from the system, MySQL 8.0.23 and the error.log:

```
    sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    !includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
    [mysqld]
    default-time-zone = "SYSTEM"

    Console commands:
    date
    Sat 01 Jan 2022 10:01:29 PM EST


    var/log/mysql/error.log
    2022-01-02T02:31:15.751387Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server]

    mysql
    mysql> SELECT NOW();
    +---------------------+
    | NOW()               |
    +---------------------+
    | 2022-01-01 22:04:43 |
    +---------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)


    mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone;
    +--------------------+
    | @@global.time_zone |
    +--------------------+
    | SYSTEM             |
    +--------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748437/mysql-select-now-out-of-sync-with-linux-date

Comment: Are you saying you want the error log timestamps to not be in utc?

Comment: What I would like is to have the time in the error.log file  be consistent with the system time and the MySQL time (i.e. 22:04:43 would be great). I also want to make sure it is in the mysql.conf.d so it is permanent.

Comment: Make everything UTC! It is my believe that the error log will always be UTC

Comment: After further research I found what I was looking for in the post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123049/how-to-change-time-zone-of-error-log-file-of-mysql   this change did the trick:    [mysqld]
log_timestamps = SYSTEM  This question is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I found what I was looking for in the post at stackoverflow.com/questions/35123049/… this change did the trick:
[mysqld]
log_timestamps = SYSTEM